# Conditionally enable Route in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created an `<Authorise />` component which renders either a 'yes' or 'no' prop based on a boolean 'allowed' prop.

```
export const Authorise = ({
  allow = false,
  yes = () => null,
  no = () => null
}) => (allow ? yes() : no());
```

`<Authorise />` component works as expected however when I try to render a `<Route />`, only the first route is rendered and the rest of the `<Route />` components are ignored.

Why is this happening? If I render the routes outside of the `<Authorise />` component it works fine. Only when rendering the components via the `<Authorise />` component does it not work and I can't work out why.

Check out my example to see the issue:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-feynman-sl6li?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/children-node

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements. Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.

If you're using a library but not playing by its rule, then something like this is what was expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your Authorize function, but because of the [Route](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) Component which will only display when the path is matched. The second issue it with [Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) which will make it that only the first matched route to be displayed

With Switch added the "/" path will always be hit since it's the first one. If you try to remove your Switch (or move the route with "/" at the end) and go to "/next" on your local dev then the /next route will be displayed

Comment: If you look at my Codesandbox it clearly shows that that is not the case. The Route is not rendered even when the route is matched. If you take the Route out of the authorise component and place it inside the switch it works.